# (W3C validator) Error: Element dl is missing a required child element

Tags: html, markup, w3c

Help to solve a mistake problem please.

```
Line 1255, Column 7: Element dl is missing a required child element.

    <dd>
```

I will be very strongly grateful.

Thanks and Best Regards.

**UPD:**

@Rolice, the open error code looks so...↓

```
<dl class="ctrlUnit submitUnit">
    <dd>
        <input type="submit" class="button primary" value="{xen:phrase log_in}" tabindex="104" data-loginPhrase="{xen:phrase log_in}" data-signupPhrase="{xen:phrase sign_up}" />
        <label for="ctrl_remember" class="rememberPassword" style="margin-left:5px"><input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" checked="checked" id="ctrl_remember" tabindex="104" /> {xen:phrase stay_logged_in}</label>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

...but correctly how to make and to solve a problem I don't know :(

P.S: Sorry my English.

**UPD:**

The problem is solved. I inserted the "dt" code before the "dd" tag and the mistake was gone in the validator. All thanks for attention. Best Regards.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl - you have to have dt, dd or both inside the DL.

Comment: Rolice, you can help me not to break the external interface? I can't understand as correctly to make :(
Code line: 1254-1259

Comment: I would suggest change the dl and dd to divs, I dont know if the dl allows such elements inside. `<dl ...` => `<div ...`, `</dl>` => `</div>` - same for `dd`.

Comment: Unfortunately writes other mistake. 
"Element dd not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

   <dd>

Contexts in which element dd may be used:
    After dt or dd elements inside dl elements.
Content model for element div:
    Flow content."

Comment: You have to change them both `dl` and `dd`. Not only dl. As I said the `dd` should also become `div`. `<dd>` => `<div>`, `</dd>` => `</div>`.

Comment: @Rolice, replacing with <dl> and <dd> on <div> I break the interface (imposition) :(

Comment: The problem is solved.
I inserted the <dt> code before the <dd> tag and the mistake was gone in the validator. All thanks for attention. Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

The correct usage of `<dl>` is like following:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Parent</dt>
  <dd>Child</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: I know Bob, but how to me to remake the existing code that everything remained without external changes? :( Code line: 1254-1259

Comment: @YudjinBo, what do you mean? This is very straight-forward solution. You cannot fix a problem without applying a fix to it.

Comment: @YudjinBo Rolice is right...